# Laravel 5.0 Model not found exception

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
try {
  $university_exists = University::where('name', '=', $university_name) - > firstOrFail();
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
  $title = "Error retrieving data";
  $message = "Entered university not found!";
  $success = 0;
  return Response::json(['title' => $title, 'message' => $message, 'success' => $success], 200);
}
```

The above code works when I give correct university name.
When I give wrong university name it throws a `model not found` exception.

Which I try to catch in the catch block. However, it doesn't get caught.

Can someone help me please?

> ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 151:
>   No query results for model [App\University].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have to import the exception class with:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
```

at the top of your file.

Comment: Perfect! nailed it. The other way is to handle it in the exception handler file in app/Exception.